# Populate nested numpy arrays with value depending on indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I hope you are having a nice day!

I need to solve a numpy problem, ideally, without using too many for loops. I want to transform a dense matrix (without any 0) into a sparse matrix (with 0).

I have two numpy arrays:

- The first with the data. As you see below, there are nested numpy arrays. The data is in the right order (and needs to be kept in the same). However, I need to add 0  when there is no index in the second numpy array. For instance, if the index 3 is not present in a nested numpy array of the indices numpy array, there should be a 0 in the third position in the array.

[data nested numpy array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ptc7.png)

- The second with the indices. As you see below, there are nested numpy arrays. The data is also in the right order (and needs to be kept in the same). The range of the indices is greater than the len of the array.

[indices nested numpy array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuUNb.png)

The result should look like [array([0, **1.6675608**, **1.6675608**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.4370337, ...], dtype=int32), ...]

There are one 0 before the first **1.6675608** and eighteen 0 after the second **1.6675608** as there are no indices present in the indices nested numpy array between 2 and 20 for the first array. I have to do that for all the arrays.

Please tell me if you have any questions, it is one of my first time posting here so I might not be clear enough.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Do the indices start from 1? In your example shouldn't there be a 0 at first?

Comment: I corrected it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with `np.put`. Example:

```
my_array = np.array([1.6,1.7,3.4,4.34,2.43,5.43,5.34,3.3,4.1])
my_indices = np.array([1,2,4]) 
new_array = np.zeros(np.max(my_indices)+1)
np.put(new_array, my_indices,my_array)
new_array 
# -> array([0. , 1.6, 1.7, 0. , 3.4, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohammad! I will test it!

Comment: Thanks again Mohammad, I found the solution thanks to you! Please see below my code:             

for (array, indices) in zip(x, y):
    new_array = np.zeros(len(z))
    np.put(new_array, indices, array)
    data_array.append(new_array)